# Angular Array of Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I'm trying to implement an Array of Observables, which observes inputs organized as a JSON object. I have a HTML document, that is able to have  (dynamically changing) multiple inputs for creating multiple users. In order, to evaluate the inputs I intend to push a JSON object to an array, when creating a new user input form. Once, I want to submit, the array is evaluated and then submitted. 
How am I gong to do this? 
Thank you in advance!

To clarify:

**HTML-Template:**

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" id="firstName1">
    <input type="text" id="lastName1">
</div>
<button (click)="createUser()">
<button (click)="submit()">
```

**Angular:**

```
users = [];

constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

createUser() {
   //DeepClone of User Input
   this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.item').cloneNode(true);
   let user = {
       firstName: FIRSTNAME_OBSERVER,
       lastName: LASTNAME_OBSERVER
    }

    /* 
      array that contains observables for each instance of .item
    */

    this.users.push(user);
}

submit() {
    // Submit Array with calculated items.
}
```

**Edit:**

```
const firstName = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#firstname').value;
const lastName = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#lastName').value;


const user = {
  firstName: Observable.of(firstName),
  lastName: Observable.of(lastName)
};

this.users.push(Observable.of(user));

Observable.forkJoin(this.users).subscribe( (res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not handling this with a form array of FormGroups?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the following:

```
Observable.forkJoin([...observable1, observable2]).subscribe(res => {
    // do some magic
    res.forEach(item => {
        this.user.push(item);
    });
})
```

Please refer to [this reference](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs). This gives you a sample of how to use it.

**EDIT**

Sorry, maybe I was not very clear on what I was suggesting, please try the following.

```
const firstName = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#firstname').value;
const lastName = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#lastName').value;


const userContant = {
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName
};

Observable.forkJoin([Observable.of(userContant )]).subscribe( (res) => {
  res.forEach(item => {
    this.user.push(item);
  })
});
```

**Maybe this way is better than your approach:**

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastName">
</div>
<button (click)="createUser()">
<button (click)="submit()">
```

Typescript:

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

createUser() {
    this.user.push({
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName
    })
}

submit() {
    // Submit Array with calculated items.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How am I going to implement the JSON object? This is at the moment my bigger problem.

Comment: @Binabiko I have updated it. Let me know if it still not work for you

Comment: Sorry I meant how am I creating an observable of the input elements? (marked with `FIRSTNAME_OBSERVER`) Sorry I'm quite new to reactive programming :/

Comment: You could create your `Observable` by `Observable.of(user1)`, `Observable.of(user2)`

Comment: It does not work. I've updated my question with my current approach

Comment: Doesn't work either. If I update the values inside the input element, the object doesn't change

Comment: You should call your submit function inside `subscribe((res) => { })`

Comment: I couldn't see you have an array of users to push into `this.user`

Comment: But if I'm doing it this way, I won't get any updates of the inputs. It doesn't work, I always receive an array of objects with the same value before changes happened

Comment: How about using jquery  use <input type=“text” id=“firstName” onkeyup=“function()> function = () => ( value = $(‘#firstName1).val() ) then add to your object, ah may have misunderstood that observables is probably a requirement

Comment: Perhaps create a promise to evaluate the array then submit after promise is done.

Comment: @Mathers theoratically yes, but doing it this way I cannot make it as dynamical as I want to, since I need to create for each ngModel a variable.

Comment: @oudekaas could you give an example approach of your promise idea? :)

Comment: Well if you want to make sure evaluation is done, do a method evaluate = ()=> {return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       //  evaluate array
            if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log('Oops, an error occured %s', err);
            }
            else {
                      resolve(res);
                      return res;
                  }
            });
        });}      the method itself this.evaluate ().then  (data => { evaluate then submit })  I guess the question is if your evaluation method is async?

Comment: I am just giving some suggestions, I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do.